# How do you construct an everywhere inward/outward-pointing vector field?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I've been recently doing some problems in John Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (Second Edition)*, and I wanted to ask how one would approach the following problem.

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary. Show that there exists a global smooth vector field on $M$ whose restriction to $\partial M$ is everywhere inward-pointing, and one whose restriction to $\partial M$ is everywhere outward-pointing.

After doing some digging in the book, I found the definition (see Page 118) that Lee is referring to when he says "inward/outward-pointing", but it's not necessarily for vector fields.

**Definition**: If $p\in M$, a vector $v\in T_pM\backslash T_p\partial M$ is said to be *inward pointing* if for some $\epsilon>0$ there exists a smooth curve $\gamma:[0,\epsilon)\to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, and it is *outward pointing* if there exists such a curve whose domain is $(-\epsilon,0]$.

My first question is how to adapt this to a vector field, and make sure that it is inward/outward-pointing everywhere. Here is my proposed definition (as far as I'm aware, it's not in the book).

**Definition (Own)**: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary, and let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$. Furthermore, let $A\subseteq \partial M$ be a closed subset. Then $X$ is said to be *inward-pointing everywhere* on $A$ if each $X_p\in T_pM$ is inward-pointing for all $p\in A$. We say that $X$ is *outward-pointing everywhere* on $A$ if $X_p\in T_pM$ is outward-pointing for all $p\in A$.

I assume that an outward/inward-pointing vector field is defined similarly. So now that all of the above groundwork has been laid out, here is my ultimate question.

**Question(s)**: Is the above definition the correct interpretation of the problem? If so, I was thinking of just applying Lemma 8.6, or trying to use Proposition 8.7 to prove the claim, but I was unsure if this was the correct approach. For those who don't have the book, these say the following.

> (Lemma 8.6). Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary, and let $A\subseteq M$ be a closed subset. Suppose that $X$ is a smooth vector field along $A$ (meaning $X_p\in T_pM$ for each $p\in A$). Given any open subset $U$ containing $A$, there exists a smooth vector global vector field $\widetilde{X}$ on $M$ such that $\widetilde{X}|_A=X$ and $\text{supp}~\widetilde{X}\subseteq U$.

> (Proposition 8.7). Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary. Given $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$, there is a smooth global vector field $X$ on $M$ such that $X_p=v$.

Any ideas for how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $A$ should be a subset of $\partial M$. Glueing together local inward-/outward pointing vector fields with partition of unity should give the vector field.

Comment: @psl2Z I'm assuming one would want to have a similar approach to proving Lemma 8.6 above, but I'm not sure what what precisely you mean by "gluing together inward/outward-pointing vector fields." Can you clarify what you mean by this, or perhaps post a pseudo answer to my question for full clarification?

Comment: Take the vector field which is zero everywhere. By your definition that is both inward and outward pointing right?

Comment: @Mark no. The phrases *outward-pointing* or *inward-pointing* refer to vectors $v\in T_pM\setminus(T_p\partial M)$, i.e necessarily are non-zero vectors.

Comment: I see. Then I think you can proceed as the other commenter suggested. For a set of charts that cover the manifold’s boundary, define the outward pointing vector field by following the coordinate that gets closer to the boundary. Then glue these vector fields together using a partition of unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throughout my answer, I will focus on *inward-pointing* vectors and vector fields; to get outward-pointing ones, just put an extra minus sign in front of the vectors and vector fields. What follows is a standard partition of unity argument.

Let us make the following two observations:

- positive linear combinations of *inward-pointing* vectors/vector fields are again inward-pointing vectors/vector fields. This should be obvious.
- for each $p\in \partial M$, there is a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ in $M$ and a vector field $X_p$ defined on $U_p$ which at all points of $U_p\cap \partial M$ is inward pointing. This is simple: given $p$, consider a chart $(U_p,\varphi=(x^1,\dots, x^n))$ which is adapted to the boundary, in the sense that $\varphi[U_p]=\Bbb{H}^n=\Bbb{R}^{n-1}\times [0,\infty)$ say. Then, the vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}$ on $U_p$ is smooth and at points of $U_p\cap\partial M$ is inward-pointing.

Let $M_0$ denote the *manifold interior* of $M$ (i.e those points of $M$ for which a chart maps diffeomorphically onto an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$, i.e $M\setminus\partial M$). For each $p\in \partial M$, let $U_p$ be a neighborhood as above and let $X_{U_p}$ be a smooth vector field as above. Then, we have an open cover $\{M_0\}\cup\{U_p\}_{p\in\partial M}$ for $M$. Fix a smooth compactly-supported partition of unity $\{\phi_0,\phi_p\}_{p\in M}$ which is subordinate to the above open cover. Now, for each $p\in\partial M$, consider the vector field $\xi_p$ defined on all of $M$ given by
\begin{align}
\xi_p(q)&:=
\begin{cases}
\phi_p(q)\cdot X_{p}(q)&\text{if $q\in U_p$}\\
0&\text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
This is clearly smooth on $U_p$; and if $q\notin U_p$, then this lies outside the support of $\phi_p$, so the complement $(\text{supp }\phi_p)^c$ is an open neighborhood of $q$ in $M$ which doesn’t intersect the support of $\phi_p$ (obviously), meaning that by definition $\xi_p$ vanishes on this open set, and hence is smooth in a neighborhood of $q$. So, $\xi_p:M\to TM$ is globally defined and smooth. Finally, consider the vector field $X:M\to TM$ given by
\begin{align}
X(q):=\sum_{p\in\partial M}\xi_p(q).\tag{1}
\end{align}
This looks like a funny infinite sum, but it’s really not, and in fact it is a smooth map because for each point $q$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $q$ in $M$ such that all but finitely many $\phi$’s (hence $\xi$’s) vanish on $V$, so on $V$, the vector field $X$ is a finite sum of smooth vector fields, hence is smooth on $V$ (so by arbitrariness of $q$, it follows $X$ is globally smooth).

All that remains is proving that $X$ is inward-pointing everywhere along the boundary. So, fix a point $q\in\partial M$; since the $\phi$’s are a *partition of unity*, we have
\begin{align}
\phi_0(q)+\sum_{p\in\partial M}\phi_p(q)=1.
\end{align}
But now keep in mind that $\text{supp }\phi_0\subset M_0$, which is disjoint from $\partial M$, so $\phi_0(q)=0$, and thus (by non-negativity of the functions) there exists atleast one index $p_*\in \partial M$ such that $\phi_{p_*}(q)>0$. This strict inequality also implies that $q\in U_{p_*}$ and hence the vector $X_{p_*}(q)$ is inward-pointing, so the vector $\xi_{p_*}(q)=\phi_{p_*}(q)\cdot X_{p_*}(q)$ is inward-pointing. So, looking back at the definition (1), we have that $X(q)$ is a (necessarily finite) sum of terms with atleast one of them being inward-pointing (namely the $\xi_{p_*}(q)$) and with all other terms being either zero or inward-pointing; hence the sum is inward-pointing. This completes the proof.

---

To recap: almost everything here is standard. The existence of $(U_p,X_p)$ is ‘obvious’. From here, get a suitable open cover of $M$ and take a partition of unity subordinate to that cover. Constructing the ‘global cutoff’ $\xi_p$ and showing its smoothness is again a standard thing. Then, considering the sum, $X$, of all the $\xi$’s is also a standard thing. Finally, all that remains is to use that fact we have a partition of unity in order to show that the constructed object $X$ has the desired property (here we just needed a strict inequality at one place, but some other times, we need the full force of the fact that the sum is equal to $1$).

Comment: An excellent answer, +1. Thank you for your help.